# Heroku Rails deployments are not using my latest javascript assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Production environment does not have recent additions to our javascript library, and I believe it's due to an issue with the build process on Heroku.

I noticed this because recent javascript additions were not working in Prod, but were working in local.  I then added some console.logs to the javascript file and found that they would always work in local, but never in Prod.

I think the issue has to do with when I build in Heroku, as I consistently get a "Yarn executable was not detected in the system." error message.  The build seems to still happen (precompiling takes 42 seconds), but I wonder if the javascript component might be breaking given the yarn error.

Here's a snippet of what I see in my logs when Heroku builds from master:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile

       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.

       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

       Asset precompilation completed (42.77s)

       Cleaning assets

       Running: rake assets:clean
```

I don't believe I'm using Yarn anywhere in this project.

I then tried to precompile directly in the Heroku environment through the terminal, but I didn't have better luck there.  Infact, I'm not even sure that it compiled anything given the reponse:

```
~ $ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
~ $ rails --version
Rails 5.2.3
```

The full log from Heroku deploy is below:

```
-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.0

-----> Vendoring libpq 5.12.1

-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.

       Using rake 12.3.3

       Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5

       Using i18n 1.6.0

       Using minitest 5.11.3

       Using thread_safe 0.3.6

       Using tzinfo 1.2.5

       Using activesupport 5.2.3

       Using builder 3.2.3

       Using erubi 1.8.0

       Using mini_portile2 2.4.0

       Using nokogiri 1.10.4

       Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3

       Using crass 1.0.4

       Using loofah 2.2.3

       Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.2.0

       Using actionview 5.2.3

       Using rack 2.0.7

       Using rack-test 1.1.0

       Using actionpack 5.2.3

       Using nio4r 2.4.0

       Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4

       Using websocket-driver 0.7.1

       Using actioncable 5.2.3

       Using globalid 0.4.2

       Using activejob 5.2.3

       Using mini_mime 1.0.2

       Using mail 2.7.1

       Using actionmailer 5.2.3

       Using activemodel 5.2.3

       Using arel 9.0.0

       Using activerecord 5.2.3

       Using mimemagic 0.3.3

       Using marcel 0.3.3

       Using activestorage 5.2.3

       Using analytics-ruby 2.0.13

       Using aws-eventstream 1.0.3

       Using aws-partitions 1.217.0

       Using aws-sigv4 1.1.0

       Using jmespath 1.4.0

       Using aws-sdk-core 3.68.0

       Using aws-sdk-kms 1.24.0

       Using aws-sdk-s3 1.48.0

       Using bcrypt 3.1.12

       Using msgpack 1.3.1

       Using bootsnap 1.4.4

       Using method_source 0.9.2

       Using thor 0.20.3

       Using railties 5.2.3

       Using bootstrap-datepicker-rails 1.8.0.1

       Using bundler 2.0.2

       Using chart-js-rails 0.1.7

       Using chartkick 3.3.0

       Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2

       Using execjs 2.7.0

       Using coffee-script 2.4.1

       Using coffee-rails 4.2.2

       Using csv 3.1.2

       Using orm_adapter 0.5.0

       Using responders 2.4.0

       Using warden 1.2.8

       Using devise 4.5.0

       Using unf_ext 0.0.7.6

       Using unf 0.1.4

       Using domain_name 0.5.20190701

       Using dotenv 2.7.5

       Using dotenv-rails 2.7.5

       Using ffi 1.11.1

       Using friendly_id 5.3.0

       Using geocoder 1.5.2

       Using groupdate 4.2.0

       Using http-cookie 1.0.3

       Using inline_svg 1.5.2

       Using jbuilder 2.9.1

       Using jquery-rails 4.3.5

       Using mime-types-data 3.2019.0904

       Using mime-types 3.3

       Using netrc 0.11.0

       Using rest-client 2.0.2

       Using mailgun-ruby 1.2.0

       Using mini_magick 4.9.5

       Using pg 0.18.4

       Using puma 3.12.1

       Using sprockets 3.7.2

       Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1

       Using rails 5.2.3

       Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3

       Using rb-inotify 0.10.0

       Using sass-listen 4.0.0

       Using sass 3.7.4

       Using tilt 2.0.9

       Using sass-rails 5.1.0

       Using social-share-button 1.2.1

       Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0

       Using turbolinks 5.2.0

       Using uglifier 4.2.0

       Bundle complete! 36 Gemfile dependencies, 95 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`

       Bundle completed (0.42s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

-----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64

-----> Detecting rake tasks

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile

       Yarn executable was not detected in the system.

       Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

       Asset precompilation completed (42.77s)

       Cleaning assets

       Running: rake assets:clean

-----> Detecting rails configuration

###### WARNING:

       You are deploying to a non-production environment: "staging".

       This is not recommended.

       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-to-a-custom-rails-environment for more information.

###### WARNING:

       We detected that some binary dependencies required to

       use all the preview features of Active Storage are not

       present on this system.



       For more information please see:

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku



###### WARNING:

       There is a more recent Ruby version available for you to use:



       2.4.9



       The latest version will include security and bug fixes, we always recommend

       running the latest version of your minor release.



       Please upgrade your Ruby version.



       For all available Ruby versions see:

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

###### WARNING:

       Potential EOL Ruby Version



       You are using a Ruby version that has either reached its End of Life (EOL)

       or will reach its End of Life on December 25th of this year.



       We suggest you upgrade to Ruby 2.5.x or later



       Once a Ruby version becomes EOL, it will no longer receive

       security updates from Ruby core and may have serious vulnerabilities.



       Please upgrade your Ruby version.



       For a list of supported Ruby versions see:

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes

###### WARNING:

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.

       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types     -> (none)

       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web

-----> Compressing...

       Done: 119.6M

-----> Launching...

       Released v119

       https://zzzz.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, what you are facing dosen't has to do nothing with yarn. I'll put you an example of this. This is similar what I see when I push to heroku (I did this 5 min ago):

`remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (23.37s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean`
So I guess is more of config of your project.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful and gives me much more focus.  Do you know where I might dig now to find the challenge? I imagine something in my config is disabling recompiling my javascript files, or not reading from application.js?

Comment: It would be nice if you share part of you code from àpplication.html.erb`and from your javascript assets. With no further code It will be kinda hard to know exactly the issue your are facing. Is there any console error form Chrome inspector? Or can you upload any images of what's not showing? That would be nice!

Comment: Upgrade your ruby version